# Is there a function to get a grid detection of only solar panels in a solar image using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working in a script using different OpenCV operations for processing an image with solar panels.

Original image:

[image: Original image]

Final image:

[image: Final image]

Can anybody help me with the code to detect only the grid lines in the image, removing the other area.

My code is the following:

```
image = cv2.imread("solar3.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Image", image)

image = cv2.resize(image, (482,406))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), 2)
cv2.imshow("blur", blur)

lap = cv2.Laplacian(blur, cv2.CV_32F)
cv2.imshow("lap",lap)

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(lap, 0, 0, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)

thresh = thresh.astype(np.uint8)

contours, hierachy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

c = 0
for i in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(i)
    if area > 1000/2:
         cv2.drawContours(image, contours, c, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    c+=1

   
cv2.imshow("Final Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can anybody help me with the code of detecting all the grids in the image.

Comment: what's the purpose of wanting that? what are you trying to solve by doing this? perhaps there are better approaches. -- do you want a topdown view of the panels? -- which grid lines do you want? the outline of every panel? the outline of every cell? or the two connecting metal strips running across all cells?

Comment: I suggest you rectify the image to a top-down view so that it is face-on. Then you can do canny edge detection on the color image. You do not need to have it as gray. Also blurring may be smoothing out edges. You might be better enhancing the contrast or using morphology to broaden the edges if they are broken up. Can you photograph the array using a drone to get a top-down view? The edges would be easier to get since the perspective makes them disappear in the distance.

Comment: I need to do a grid detection in these kind of images, only the grid lines inside each panel. Can we do using open cv functions to get grid lines in the entire image.

Comment: @sweety It would help if you first segment each panel separately

Comment: The cell lines for the edges fade in the distance. So they would be very hard to extract. Perhaps making the image into face-on view and some contrast enhancement might help.